# Open webpages without refreshing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a navigation menu and I want to switch between webpages without refreshing the whole site. For example Info is pressed it will appear and the homepage or Contact will disappear.

```
<nav id="menu">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="javascript:appear('Home');">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="javascript:appear('Info');">Info</a></li>
   <li><a href="javascript:appear('Contact');">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I started to create my initial header, but it is not interpreted correctly, therefor I am stuck. This is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function appear {
   var item = document.getElementById;
   if (item) {
   if(item.className == "Show") {
      item.className = "Hide"
  } 
   else {
   item.className = "Show"
  }
</script>
```

Here is ¨Show¨ and ¨Hide¨ defined in a css file:

```
#Home.Hide, #Info.Hide, #Contact.Hide {
 display: none;
}

#Home.Show, #Info.Show, #Contact.Show {
 display: block;
}
```

Comment: What you are talking about is called a SPA.  Single  Page Application.  It is, as stated, as single page that utilizing hash routing and some nifty tricks to update the page without refreshing the browser.  Look into things like DURandal, and Sammy

Comment: There is no such thing as `8divID`. Even if there was there is no such element with id `Home` in your DOM.

Comment: @QBM5 Thanks for you comment, but DURandal or Sammy is not a solution for me. I am looking for a client side script.

Comment: That doesn't fix anything. [`getElementById` is a method on the `document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Comment: Both of my suggestions are client side libraries used to facilitate SPA applications.  You can look into SPA design concepts if you want to build something from scratch

Answer (score -1):

Are looking for jQuery AJAX load?

```
function appear() { 
   $.ajax({
        url: "info.html", 
        success: function(result){
        $(".ClassName").html(result);
    }});
 });
}
```

or do it with another way:

```
function appear() {
    $(".ClassName").load("info.html");
});
```

use the click function to activate li

```
$("li:nth-of-type(2)").click(function(){
   put your code here...
});
```